# An error occurred while starting a transaction on the provider connection. See the inner exception for details

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

This is my coding. It shows error like
An error occurred while starting a transaction on the provider connection. See the inner exception for details.

```
       DemoEntities db = DemoEntities.CreateNewDemoEntity();
       var query = (from f in db.Product_Table
                    where f.ReportID == reportID && f.StateID == stateID
                    select f);
       foreach(var q in query)
       {
           Custom_Search_Transformation cst = new Custom_Search_Transformation()
           {
               CustomerID = customerID,
               StateID = stateID,
               FullProductID = q.FullProductID
           };
           db.Custom_Search_Transformation.AddObject(cst);
           db.SaveChanges();
       }
```

Comment: "See the inner exception for details" is there for a reason.

Comment: I found the issue db.SaveChanges(); should comes outside of the foreach loop

Comment: Sure, but in a SO question it's always a good idea to show what the inner exception told you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `db.SaveChanges();` should come outside of the `foreach` loop:

```
DemoEntities db = DemoEntities.CreateNewDemoEntity();
var query = (from f in db.Product_Table
             where f.ReportID == reportID && f.StateID == stateID
             select f);
foreach(var q in query)
{
    Custom_Search_Transformation cst = new Custom_Search_Transformation()
    {
        CustomerID = customerID,
        StateID = stateID,
        FullProductID = q.FullProductID
    };
    db.Custom_Search_Transformation.AddObject(cst);          
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Done the same but still getting same error. One thing is that I am running it in a thread

Answer (score 17):

Make your Queryable lists to .ToList() it should work fine.

Comment: Sometimes you have to save data to the DB at the end of Each Loop. If this is the case, as this answer explains it  "var q in query.ToList" solves the problem.

Comment: I had this issue, and I have to save the data during each iteration to grab the ID out of a record to use for tracking purposes with a 3rd-party system. Running a `.ToList()` before looping allowed me to iterate over those items without keeping the transaction open, making the `SaveChanges` call work no problem.