# Updating database using SubmitChanges

Tags: database, sql-update, try-catch, savechanges, inner-exception

I'm trying to update a record in a database through C# code. I found a solution that I think should work using SaveChanges. However, I'm getting an error from my catch statement that says: "An error occurred while starting a transaction on the provider connection. See the inner exception for details." I'm either looking for an answer on how to fix it and/or how to make my catch statement give better details on what the problem actually is.

This is my code.

```
        using var orderContext =
            new OrderContext(Resources.SqlAuthenticationConnectionString);

        foreach(OrderRecord order in orders)
        {
            var query =
                from o in orderContext.OrderRecords
                where o.ID == order.ID
                select o;
            foreach(OrderRecord record in query)
            {
                record.HeatLotNumber = order.HeatLotNumber;
                record.OrderNumber = order.OrderNumber;
                record.ShimCenterMaterial = order.ShimCenterMaterial;
                try
                {
                    orderContext.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I didn't look hard enough. Here's what my problem was. The save needs to be outside the foreach loop.

[An error occurred while starting a transaction on the provider connection. See the inner exception for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21306377/an-error-occurred-while-starting-a-transaction-on-the-provider-connection-see-t)